# Iterate over lists of maps to to check for not matching values

Tags: elixir

I don't have idea how to approach my problem. My problem is that in one app I'm getting records from two other servers. I'm receiving such lists (from IO.inspect):

```
[
  "node_name": [
    %{
      id: "e5016e16-3e35-4241-9cba-aa3c428f17c5",
      ## bunch of other fields
    },
    %{
      id: "773c8dbe-954f-42a1-a72a-045f25d0cd8c",
      ## bunch of other fields
    }
  ],
  "node_2_name": [
    %{
      other_id: "773c8dbe-954f-42a1-a72a-045f25d0cd8b",
      id: 1,
      ## bunch of other fields
    },
    %{
      id: 2,
      other_id: "e5016e16-3e35-4241-9cba-aa3c428f17c5", 
      ## bunch of other fields

    }
  ]
]
```

What I want to do is to find records where other_id does not match any id in the first list and vice-versa, id from the first list does not have matching any other_id. Then I want to add some fields (i.e. name, surname) to the maps and finally insert those records with not matching ids in my app.

As I said I don't really have an idea how to start and complete this. I'm not waiting for the ready solution but rather looking for some advice (what functions use etc.) and guidance how to achieve results I want.

Answer (score 0):

The `MapSet` module has functions that could be of use to you.  Consider the following:

```
data_node1 = [
  %{
    id: "e5016e16-3e35-4241-9cba-aa3c428f17c5"
    ## bunch of other fields
  },
  %{
    id: "773c8dbe-954f-42a1-a72a-045f25d0cd8c"
    ## bunch of other fields
  }
]

data_node2 = [
  %{
    other_id: "773c8dbe-954f-42a1-a72a-045f25d0cd8b",
    id: 1
    ## bunch of other fields
  },
  %{
    id: 2,
    other_id: "e5016e16-3e35-4241-9cba-aa3c428f17c5"
    ## bunch of other fields
  }
]

ids_node1 = data_node1 |> Enum.map(fn %{id: id} -> id end) |> MapSet.new()
other_ids_node2 = data_node2 |> Enum.map(fn %{other_id: other_id} -> other_id end) |> MapSet.new()

# ["773c8dbe-954f-42a1-a72a-045f25d0cd8c"]
IO.inspect(MapSet.difference(ids_node1, other_ids_node2) |> Enum.to_list())
```

Answer (score 0):

The arguably easiest and definitely the most powerful way to deal with deeply nested structures in [elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir) would be [`Access`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Access.html).

To get all the values under `key` from `data`, one might use: `get_in(data, [node, Access.all(), Access.key(key)])`. To filter out uniques: `get_in(data, [node, Access.filter(fn %{id: id} -> id not in others end)])`. To sum it up:

```elixir
defmodule Getter do
  @data […] # your data for tests
  def get_ids(data \\ @data, node, key) do
    get_in(data, [node, Access.all(), Access.key(key)])
  end
  def get_distinct(data \\ @data, node, key, others) do
    get_in(data, [node, Access.filter(& &1.id not in others)])
  end
end
```

And use it like:

```elixir
other_ids = Getter.get_ids(:node_2_name, :other_id)
Getter.get_distinct(:node_name, :id, other_ids)
#⇒ [%{id: "773c8dbe-954f-42a1-a72a-045f25d0cd8c"}]
```

Now one might directly map this list, or even use `update_in/3` to amend the original list in-place.

Answer (score 0):

This was asked recently on the [Elixir Forum](https://elixirforum.com/t/filter-nested-list-of-maps-by-not-matching-id/53213), so I'll repeat the answer I gave there:

```elixir
defmodule Example do
  def run do
    list1 = [%{id: 12345}, %{id: 54321}]
    list2 = [%{id: 56789, other_id: 12345}, %{id: 0987, other_id: 7456}]

    # Extract the IDs from each list into sets
    list1_ids = MapSet.new(list1, & &1.id)
    list2_other_ids = MapSet.new(list2, & &1.other_id)

    # Find only the IDs that are not in the other list
    list1_ids_not_in_list2 = MapSet.difference(list1_ids, list2_other_ids)
    list2_other_ids_not_in_list1 = MapSet.difference(list2_other_ids, list1_ids)

    # Select only the items from the original lists corresponding to the above IDs
    list1_with_no_match = Enum.filter(list1, &(&1.id in list1_ids_not_in_list2))
    list2_with_no_match = Enum.filter(list2, &(&1.other_id in list2_other_ids_not_in_list1))

    # Join the lists together
    list1_with_no_match ++ list2_with_no_match
  end
end
```

Usage:

```elixir
iex(1)> Example.run
[%{id: 54321}, %{id: 987, other_id: 7456}]
```

Comment: Hello and thank you, this is what I am looking for. I have only one issue. I was trying to get the value of id/other id with get_in but I failed. Do you have an idea how to get those values from a map that is inside of "node_2_name": ?

Comment: I mean, that MapSet.new(list1, & &1.id) this won't work  because id is in a map that is inside of  "node_name": [...]

Comment: You can pattern match the list: `[node_name: list1, node_2_name: list2] = input`. Or you can use the access operator: `list1 = input[:node_name]`